# vscode cannot reconnect to existing jupyter notebook server when waking my laptop

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I recently switched from browser to vs code for using jupyter notebook and the IDE-like features (e.g. auto-complete, debugging, etc) provided by VS code is really so much better than a browser. But one thing bothers me is that **whenever I wake my laptop from sleep mode**, it often has issue re-connecting to existing jupyter notebook server (in my case localhost:8888). When using browser, I simply refresh the page and it works. But VS code does not seem to be able to "reconnect" to the server. I also tried close/reopen my ipynb notebook, but still no luck. I could just restart the server, but I would lose all my saved results so it is usually not the best option.

Edit:

"Help: about" in my VScode returns:

```
Version: 1.84.2
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:52:33.687Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.3.0
```

Following are my jupyter extension versions:

```
@ijmbarr/jupyterlab_spellchecker v0.2.0  enabled  OK
```

Comment: Does this work if you use command `Developer: Reload Window` in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT no, it does not work

Comment: Are there any related messages in the Output Panel's various channels- especially the ones for Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: 2) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 3) Please also include the version numbers of your Jupyter extension(s)

Comment: > "Are there any related messages in the Output Panel's various channels" @starball no there are no output info

Comment: @starball I have updated my version and "Help: About" info in the post